# Midrash about hitting thumb with hammer to show that we should not take vengeance on another Jew

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash

Rav Zamir Cohen recounted a Midrash for parashat Vi-Yi’hi, which talks about how we need to have אהבת חינם since כל יהודי ערב זה בזה

To buttress the point he says there is a midrash, which says that if you bang your thumb with a hammer, the hurt hand won’t attack the other (likewise, we should not get angry at a fellow Jew).

However, I can’t find the source of this midrash. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 7):

The source is the *Y'rushalmi* ([*N'darim* 9:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3309.htm)), speaking about the prohibition to take revenge against a fellow Jew ("Do not take revenge or bear a grudge against the children of your people" [*Vayikra* 19:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0319.htm#18)):

> היך עבידא הוה מקטע קופד ומחת סכינא לידוי תחזור ותמחי לידיה

Translation:

> What is this case [comparable to]? If someone was cutting a piece of meat, and the knife fell onto his hand. Would he then bring down the knife again on his [other] hand [in revenge]?